# ERROR 1064 when importing self-contained file in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, mysql-workbench

I use MySQL Workbench 8.0. I have a database file in SQLite 3 format, which I want to import into SQL Workbench for later reverse engineering. When I import the file, I get the following error:

*"ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRANSACTION' at line 1
Operation failed with exitcode 1"*

The beginning of the .sqlite file looks like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ZATTACHMENT`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ZATTACHMENT` (
    `Z_PK`  INTEGER,
    `Z_ENT` INTEGER,
```

Any clues about this? I am quite new to the SQL syntax.

Comment: Please show the rest of the create table statement. Also you don't need a begin transaction with DDL statements..

Comment: MySQL does not support transactional DDL, so starting the transaction doesn't make sense to begin with

Answer (score 0):

In MySql, it's START TRANSACTION, not BEGIN TRANSACTION.

SQL is like that.  Minor incompatibilities between table server makes and models are a pain in the xxx neck.

Comment: 'BEGIN and BEGIN WORK are supported as aliases of START TRANSACTION for initiating a transaction. START TRANSACTION is standard SQL syntax, is the recommended way to start an ad-hoc transaction, and permits modifiers that BEGIN does not.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html but not appropriate for DDL statements anyway

Comment: Thank you. This worked, however, the program returns an error for the second line DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ZATTACHMENT`;. Is there anything obviously wrong here?

Comment: @T-StoneLeif you shouldn't accept answers before testing , it just discourages others from looking. And I cannot reproduce your issue https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eUBon3mRjXcJWXQykhxSNT/0